# I put two buttons over a background image. The problem is I coded hover for those buttons but they are showing the change

Tags: html, css

I am trying to give a hover effect on two buttons. So, I put two buttons over a background image. The problem is I coded hover for those buttons but they are showing the change. But, when I hide the background image the hover effect is working perfectly. Please tell me what mistake I am doing?

simplified HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Harry Fitness</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">        
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container top-container">
        <div class="left">
            <img src="logo.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="mid">
            <ul>
                <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Products</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Calender</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>About Us</li></a>
            </ul>    
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <button class="btn">Call Us Now</button>
            <button class="btn">Email Us</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my css coding:

```
    *{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;    
        background-image: url(athletic-young-female-runner-jogger-stylish-sportswear-running-against-blank- 
        wall-having-concentrated-focused-look-going-win-sprint-endurance-race.jpg);
        background-size: 2000px 1000px ;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        color: black
    }
.left{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
}
.left img{
    height: 100px;
    width: 110px;
}
.mid{
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 600px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.mid li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.mid li a:hover{
    background-color: white;
}
.right{
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 34px;
    top:22px
    border: 2px solid yellow;

}
.btn{
    margin: 0px 9px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Here I used the hover effect below. but the background color is not changing. I tried in multiple browser but it's not working.

```
.btn:hover{
    background-color: rgb(31, 30, 30);
}
```

Then I tried the hover effect hiding the background image. The code is below.

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    /* background-image: url(athletic-young-female-runner-jogger-stylish-sportswear-running-against-blank-wall-having-concentrated-focused-look-going-win-sprint-endurance-race.jpg);
    background-size: 2000px 1000px ; */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: black
}
.btn{
    margin: 0px 9px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.btn:hover{
    background-color: rgb(31, 30, 30);
}
```

This time it worked. The hover effect is working. The background color of the buttons are changed.
But, I want both the background image visible and the hover effect still work. Please help me out through this problem.

Comment: seems to be working fine.  what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @DCR, they have mentioned: *Here I used the hover effect below. but the background color is not changing. I tried in multiple browser but it's not working.*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the buttons (as well as all other elements) are being given a background image due to the CSS having * {....}.

Background images take precedence over background-color so even when you hover the background-image carries on being shown (well, only a tiny part of it as the buttons are small).

Change the * for body (if that's where you want the background-image to be).

While we are looking at the code, I believe your unordered list children should be li elements, not a elements so they should  look like this:

```
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

this reordering should also mean that the CSS for hovering on those elements should also now work.